# Object doesn't support property or method 'filter'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm running into an IE8 issue which I initially thought was due to lack of IE8 support for indexOf() property but that didn't seem to be the case. I implemented the indexOf() through prototype but still keep getting the error messsage -

Object doesn't support property or method 'filter'

My code is and it errors out on the passedArray.filter line.

```
  function consolidatedFilters(passedArray, passedFilter, passedFilterType)
    if (passedFilterType == "specialty")
    {       
        var filteredArray = passedArray.filter(
            function(el)
            {
               for (i in passedFilter) 
               {
                    if (passedFilter[i] == el[8]) 
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
               }
               return false
             }
        );      
        return filteredArray;
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Array.filter isn't cross-browser compliant, you'll have to prototype that onto Array.  You also may want to verify that the array you are filtering is never typeof 'undefined'

Update:
MDN provides a reference to how to prototype filter onto array:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: +1, You would need IE9+ for a native .filter in IE; http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: @Alex thanks I was looking for something similar! Didn't know there was a whole J/S compatibility table for browsers just like for CSS.

Comment: I am trying to invoke with   **function isBigEnough(value) {
  return value >= 10;
}
var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough);**

Comment: in browser console and I see old result